# SQL - Videos in Subcategories of categories

Tags: php, mysql, sql, video, categories

Hoping for some help here. I have the following SQL tables and I'm trying to return the names of the subcategories that have videos and amount of videos in each of the subcategories.  (As the videos can be apart of a maximum of 3 multiple categories/subcategories, there are 3 sets of cat/subcat ids on the video tables).  Thank you for any assistance.

- Table: Categories, Fields: `id, cat_name`
- Table: Subcategories, Fields: `id, cat_name_id, subcat_name`
- Table: Videos, Fields: `id, cat_name_id_1, subcat_name_1, cat_name_id_2, subcat_name_2, cat_name_id_3, subcat_name_3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by and count to get the result you want.

```
SELECT subcat_name
    ,count(id) Videos
FROM (
    SELECT subcat_name_1 AS subcat_name
        ,Videos.id
    FROM Videos

    UNION ALL

    SELECT subcat_name_2 AS subcat_name
        ,Videos.id
    FROM Videos

    UNION ALL

    SELECT subcat_name_3 AS subcat_name
        ,Videos.id
    FROM Videos
    ) unionFromVideos
GROUP BY subcat_name
```

Comment: This got me to what I was needing.  Thank you for the assistance.